# GLSL Uniforms being removed that are used within a switch statement

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

OK-- I am trying to create a OpenGL program that uses multiple texutre libraries -- and I am using the ones digit of my texture coordinate to decide which library to use. To do this, I have to use a switch - case statement, which the compiler seems to think unrelevent and removes it, causing my glGetUniformLocation call to fail. Here is my GLSL code:

vertex shader:

```
    // define the version of GLSL to use

        #version 330 core

        // location and render order. Both defined for all verticies using a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
        layout(location = 0) in vec2 in_location;
        layout(location = 1) in vec2 in_UV;

        // uniforms
        uniform int renderOrder;
        uniform mat4 viewMat;


        // data to be sent and interpolated to the fragment shader
        out vec2 UV;

        // entry point
        void main()
        {
            // gl_Position is a special vec3 that defines the location in space.

            // set the final position
            vec4 location = vec4(in_location, (9.f - renderOrder) / 9.f, 1.f);
            gl_Position = (viewMat * location);

            // send the data to the fragment shader and interpolates it so it has the correct value
            UV = in_UV;
        }


fragment shader:

    // define the version of GLSL to use
#version 330 core

// the texture object we can query from
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
uniform sampler2D tex3;
uniform sampler2D tex4;
uniform sampler2D tex5;
uniform sampler2D tex6;
uniform sampler2D tex7;
uniform sampler2D tex8;
uniform sampler2D tex9;
uniform sampler2D tex10;
uniform sampler2D tex11;
uniform sampler2D tex12;
uniform sampler2D tex13;
uniform sampler2D tex14;
uniform sampler2D tex15;
uniform sampler2D tex16;

// the UV that we interpolated and sent here in the vertex shader
in vec2 UV;

// the output
out vec4 color;


void main()
{
    // use the texture2D method to get the color at the corresponding texture location using the filtering method provided.
    // http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tut15%20Magnification.html
    // also filps Y coordinate of UVs

    int texID = int(floor(UV.x));

    switch (texID)
    {
    case 0:
        color = texture2D(tex0, UV);
    case 1:
        color = texture2D(tex1, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 2:
        color = texture2D(tex2, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 3:
        color = texture2D(tex3, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 4:
        color = texture2D(tex4, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 5:
        color = texture2D(tex5, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 6:
        color = texture2D(tex6, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 7:
        color = texture2D(tex7, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 8:
        color = texture2D(tex8, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 9:
        color = texture2D(tex9, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 10:
        color = texture2D(tex10, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 11:
        color = texture2D(tex11, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 12:
        color = texture2D(tex12, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 13:
        color = texture2D(tex13, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 14:
        color = texture2D(tex14, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 15:
        color = texture2D(tex15, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));
    case 16:
        color = texture2D(tex16, vec2(UV.x - texID, UV.y - texID));

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

My GPU is a NVIDIA GTX 970
driver version 347.25

Comment: Not what you've asked for, but did you ever have a look at the concept of a texture atlas. It might simplify and speed up your shader quite a bit.

Comment: I am using a texture atlas, multiple of them. The idea of this is the selection of which atlas to use based upon the ones digit of the texture coordinates.

Comment: Rather than using a 17 texture unifiorms and a switch statement, have you tried making your uniform an array of samplers and indexing directly? i.e. uniform sampler2D texArray[17]; accessed by color = texture2D( texArray[texID] ...

Answer (score 0):

Alright. My problem seem to has been fixed by putting breaks in each case. No clue why this would make a difference, but it fixes the problem.

Comment: you may consider reading up what breaks in switches are used for in general

Comment: Without breaks, the value assigned to `color` would always come from `tex16`. So the assignments in the other case statements would be redundant, and the corresponding uniforms can be eliminated.